# Separation of variables (PDE)

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'd like to solve the following problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u+au=1 & \text{in}\,\ \Omega=\,(0,1)\times(0,1)\\
u=0 & \text{on}\,\,\partial\Omega\backslash\{y=0\}\\
\partial_\nu u=x & \text{on} \,\{y=0\}
\end{cases}
$$
using the separation of variables: 
$$
u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)
$$
But I think I need all boundary conditions $= 0$ in order to use that method, am I right? Or I can proceed without problems?

Comment: It suffices to take the general solution for the problem with $0$ on the boundary and add any non-homogeneous solution (that is, any one solution to this particular problem).

Comment: But on $\{y=0\}$ there is a Neumann condition and I don't know how to work with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separation of variables is not to be understood literally as just substituting $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$, though it might be most helpful for constructing certain explicit partial solutions to some nonlinear PDE. For the linear PDE, a scripture $u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$  is to be treated rather as a historical landmark, while nowadays separation of  variables  requires first to single out a suitable self-adjoint Sturm-Liouville problem in one variable with eigenfunctions that form an orthogonal basis in $L^2$. Though generally plausible, a hypothetical case when no self-adjoint Sturm-Liouville problem can be found requires far more advanced approach not needed for this simple problem. The desired solution is expanded then into Fourier series *w.r.t.* the basis of eigenfunctions with appropriate boundary value problems for Fourier coefficients treated as functions in another variable.

The choice of a Sturm-Liouville problem in variable $x$ looks less troublesome, and so
consider the Sturm-Liouville problem 
$$
\begin{cases}
X''=\lambda X,\;x\in (0,1),\\
X(0)=X(1)=0,
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
X_n(x)=\sin{(n\pi x)},\\
\lambda_n=-\pi^2n^2,\;n\geqslant 1,
\end{cases}
$$ 
with eigenfunctions that form an orthogonal basis in $L^2(0,1)$. Expanding the desired solution into Fourier series
$$
u(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}Y_n(y)\sin{(n\pi x)},\qquad
Y_n(y)=\frac{(u,X_n)}{\|X_n\|^2}=2\!\int\limits_0^1\! u(x,y)\sin{(n\pi x)}\,dx,\;
n\geqslant 1,
$$
where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the inner product in the Lebesgue space $L^2(0,1)$ with the norm $\|\cdot\|$. Multiplying the equation $u_{xx}+u_{yy}+au=1$ by an eigenfunction
$X_n$ *w.r.t.* the inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ yields boundary value problems for the Fourier coefficients $Y_n$\, namely
$$
\begin{align*}
Y_n''+(a-\pi^2n^2)Y_n=c_n\overset{\rm def}{=}\frac{(1,X_n)}{\|X_n\|^2}=
2\!\int\limits_0^1\!\sin{(n\pi x)}\,dx,\\
-Y_n'(0)=\alpha_n\overset{\rm def}{=}\frac{(x,X_n)}{\|X_n\|^2}=
2\!\int\limits_0^1\!x\sin{(n\pi x)}\,dx,\quad
Y_n(1)=0,\;n\geqslant 1,
\end{align*}
$$
with  $\nu$ understood as an outward normal to the boundary portion $\{y=0\}$.
It is clear that
$$
c_n=\begin{cases}
\frac{4}{\pi(2k+1)}\,\;n=2k+1,\\
0,\quad n=2k,
\end{cases}
\qquad
\alpha_n=-\frac{2(-1)^n}{\pi n}\;n\geqslant 1.
$$
Thus for $n=2k$ we get the boundary value problems with homogeneous equations 
$$
\begin{align*}
Y_{2k}''(y)+(a-4\pi^2k^2)Y_{2k}(y)=0,\;y\in (0,1),\\
Y'_{2k}(0)=\frac{1}{\pi k}\,,\quad Y_{2k}(1)=0,\quad k\geqslant 1,
\end{align*}\tag{$\ast$}
$$
while for $n=2k+1$ we get the boundary value problems with inhomogeneous equations 
$$
\begin{align*}
Y_{2k+1}''(y)+\bigl(a-\pi^2(2k+1)^2\bigr)Y_{2k+1}(y)=
\frac{4}{\pi(2k+1)},\;y\in (0,1),\\
Y'_{2k+1}(0)=-\frac{2}{\pi(2k+1)}\,,\quad Y_{2k+1}(1)=0,\quad k\geqslant 0.
\end{align*}\tag{$\ast\ast$}
$$ 
Given $a\leqslant 0$, each and every problem $(\ast)$, $(\ast\ast)$ has a unique 
solution for any $k\geqslant 0$ readily to be found from $(\ast)$ and 
$(\ast\ast)$.  The picture looks more sophisticated when values $a>0$ are allowed. 
Each and every problem $(\ast)$, $(\ast\ast)$ still does possess a unique 
solution for any $k\geqslant 0$, readily to be found from $(\ast)$ and 
$(\ast\ast)$, if and only if $a$ does not take any of the critical values 
$\,a=-\lambda_{mj}\,$ with $\,\lambda_{mj}<0\,$ being the eigenvalues of the Laplace operator with homogeneous boundary conditions of the same type, *i.e.*,
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta v=\lambda v & \text{in}\,\ \Omega=\,(0,1)\times(0,1)\\
v=0 & \text{on}\,\,\partial\Omega\backslash\{y=0\}\\
\partial_\nu v=0& \text{on} \,\{y=0\}.
\end{cases}
$$
Employing the same separation of variables techniques as above, it is not difficult to find all eigenvalues and eigenfunctions
$$
v_{mj}(x,y)=\sin{(m\pi x)}\cos{\bigl[\bigl(j+\frac{1}{2}\bigr)\pi y\bigr]},\quad
\lambda_{mj}=-\bigl[m^2+\bigl(j+\frac{1}{2}\bigr)^2\bigr]\pi^2,\;\;m\geqslant 1,\;
j\geqslant 0.
$$
For the problem under consideration, the necessary and sufficient condition of solvability can be obtained  multiplying the equation by an eigenfunction 
$\,v_{mj}\,$ *w.r.t.* the inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)$. Namely,
$$
\int\limits_{\Omega}\!\Delta u v_{mj}dx\,dy+a\!\int\limits_{\Omega}\! u v_{mj}dx\,dy=
\int\limits_{\Omega}\!v_{mj}dx\,dy
$$
Applying Green's formula and using boundary conditions yields
$$
\int\limits_0^1\! x v_{mj}(x,0)\,dx+(a+\lambda_{mj})\!\int\limits_{\Omega}\! u v_{mj}dx\,dy=
\int\limits_{\Omega}\!v_{mj}dx\,dy,
$$
whence follows
$$
2\alpha_m+(a+\lambda_{mj})\gamma_{mj}=c_m\frac{4(-1)^j}{\pi(2j+1)}
$$
with $\gamma_{mj}$ standing for Fourier coefficients of the desired solution $\,u\,$
*w.r.t.* the orthogonal basis $\{v_{mj}\}$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. When coefficient $a$
does take one of the critical values $a=-\lambda_{mj}\,$, the necessary and sufficient condition of solvability takes the form
$$
\alpha_m=c_m\frac{2(-1)^j}{\pi(2j+1)}.
$$
It  is clear that the latter condition does not hold for all $m\geqslant 1$ and 
$j\geqslant 0$. Hence, for any ctritical value of the coefficient $a=-\lambda_{mj}\,$,
the desired solution $u$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be okay, since:

$u=0,\text{ on }\partial\Omega\setminus\{y=0\}\Rightarrow u(x,y)=0\Rightarrow X(x)=0$ on the $x$ boundaries.

And $u(x,y)=0\Rightarrow Y(y)=0$ on the $y=1$ boundary.

At $y=0$, $\partial_\nu u =(u_x,u_y)\cdot(0,1)=u_y=X(x)Y'(y)=x\Rightarrow X(x)=x,Y(0)=1$

It's only this last part $\partial_\nu=x$, that may cause problems, tell me how it goes!